# Set a Boolean if Kafka Connection Succeeds

Tags: scala, apache-kafka

I would like to log to Kafka if I can reach a broker, but simply skip it if Kafka is not available. To that end, I'd like to set the Boolean variable `useKafka` but I can't find an elegant way of doing this.

Below is my attempt.

```
...
      val props = new Properties()
      props.put("bootstrap.servers", kafkaBroker)
      props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
      props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
      props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
      props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
      props.put("request.timeout.ms", 200);

      var useKafka: Boolean = true

      // This is kludgy
      val producer = try {
        new KafkaProducer[String, String](props)
      }
      catch {
        useKafka = false
      }

...
```

Results in the following error at compile time: `value isDefinedAt is not a member of Unit`

Here is how I intend to use the Boolean in the code:

```
if (useKafka) producer.send(new ProducerRecord[String, String](kafkaTopic, "cobol", logStr))
```

## Edit 2 June 2022

Based on Dima's answer, I changed my code as follows.

A KafkaConsumer throws an error and is better for testing. By using a Future with a timeout, I can wait for a reasonable amount of time.

```
      val simpleConsumer = new org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer[String, String](props)
      val testKafka = Try {Await.ready(Future(simpleConsumer.listTopics), 200  milliseconds)}.toOption

useKafka = testKafka.nonEmpty
```

Comment: 1) your error message does not relate to the code you show 2) consider using Scala's `Try` 3) I suspect you're assigning the `if` expression to some variable but it's type is `Unit`, thus the error

Comment: You should use `AdminClient.describeCluster` to test connectivity _without_ (accidentally) sending data to a topic. Creating a new Producer doesn't actually try to connect

Answer (score 1):

Just get rid of the flag and make producer optional.

```
   val producer = Try { new KafkaProducer[String, String](props) }.toOption
```

Then, to log:

```
    producer.foreach(_.send(new ProducerRecord(...))
```

Or, if you still need a boolean for some reason, `def useKafka = producer.nonEmpty`

Comment: I don't think this constructor throws an exception, btw

Comment: Thank you @Dima. I added an edit to my question with respect to the Boolean. Would you mind updating your answer with the consumer as the test instead? OneCricketeer is right that the producer does not throw an error.

Comment: @LarsSkaug waiting on the future is a really bad idea ... Why do you care so much about setting that boolean in the first place? Just `send` unconditionally and ignore errors - will get the same effect.

Comment: Would you mind explaining why waiting for this future is such a bad idea? It's to test whether I can reach the Kafka cluster.

Comment: @LarsSkaug waiting for background things to complete is generally "code smell" in scala, because having to do it typically signals a systemic problem (aside from other, "immediate" considerations of blocking threads, like deadlocks, starvation, etc.). In this particular case, for example, what happens if the cluster is available _right now_,  but not a millisecond later?